# Push Rails / ClearDB App to Heroku Error 'Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Every time I run:

```
git push heroku master
```

I get the following error:

```
Running: rake assets:precompile
rake aborted!
Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1'
```

I am running

```
rails -v Rails 3.2.11
```

and

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
```

I have installed ClearDB via Heroku CLI and it seems to work fine, but I can't figure out this error.

Here is my yml for production:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  host: localhost
  database: pm_production
  username: root
  password: root
  allow_concurrency: true
  pool: 5
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your app is trying to initialize during asset compilation. The [heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar) explicitly recommend you disable app initialization on precompile by modifying your `config/application.rb`:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

Comment: +1 I've been trying to fix this for hours, finally this worked